# Symfony Console tab completion

Tags: php, symfony, command-line-interface, tab-completion

I have an application with a Symfony Console based CLI. The application does not use the Symfony framework, just the Symfony Console component.

When I execute

```
php app/myapp
```

I get the usual overview with the name, version, options and registered commands shown. Suppose I just have one command, called "displaykittens". What I want to be able to do is

```
php app/myapp d <TAB>
```

And have it complete to

```
php app/myapp displaykittens
```

As is kinda expected in a modern unix environment. Unfortunately there appears to be no tab completion whatsoever. The Console Component itself [provides an utility that allows doing something along these lines](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-2-autocomplete-on-the-command-line) in commands themselves. That does not help me with getting tab completion for the commands though. Is this possible somehow?

Comment: Have you tried using the interactive shell mode for the symfony2 console?  `php app/myapp -s`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Application class of the Console component can be wrapped in a [Shell class](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Console/Shell.html), provided by the same component. That provides some amount of auto completion.

According to people on the #symfony IRC on freenode, there is no way to have the console app provide autocompletion out of the box, since changes to the shell config need to be made.

Answer (score 4):

Symfony 5.4+ has autocompletion natively.
You can get more information about autocompletion with `bin/console completion --help`.

For example with bash you can add this in your `~/.bashrc`.

```
eval "$(/var/www/app/bin/console completion bash)"
```

Official announcement: https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-4-console-autocompletion

Answer (score 3):

You might like this extension https://github.com/stecman/symfony-console-completion
It allows you to set up both active commands and  our own suggestions

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is possible with the normal `bash` shell. But if you use `zsh` you can install `oh-my-zsh`. There is a great *plugin* that does exactly what you ask for: [Oh-My-ZSH Symfony2 plugin](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Plugins#symfony2)

Answer (score 0):

I use (and have had some PRs accepted) on https://github.com/bamarni/symfony-console-autocomplete

I have several Symfony Console apps in the teams dev setup.

Our own `wu` (Workflow Utilities), `composer`, `artisan` (Laravel), and `phinx` (Rob Morgan -> CakeDB migration tool).

So, I have this script:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo Building bash auto-completion for artisan
./vendor/bin/symfony-autocomplete ./artisan > $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion.d/artisan

echo Building bash auto-completion for composer
./vendor/bin/symfony-autocomplete composer > $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion.d/composer

echo Building bash auto-completion for phinx
./vendor/bin/symfony-autocomplete ./vendor/robmorgan/phinx/bin/phinx > $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion.d/phinx

echo Building bash auto-completion for wu
./vendor/bin/symfony-autocomplete ./wu > $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion.d/wu

echo Recycle your terminal to load the auto-completions.
```

And the line```
"update-autocomplete": "scripts/update-autocomplete.sh"

```
in the `scripts` array in my `composer.json`.

And I install the tool into my global composer setup.

Happy to help more if this is an appropriate tool for you.
```